# Recursive call and how object is iterating in tree

Tags: c#

I stumble upon this piece of code as i am learning oop so it is bit confusing for me. I am implementing binary search tree and this particular function implement IN-Order traversal.

```
 class Binary_Tree
{
    //Nodes class Inner class.
    public class Nodes
     {

         public Nodes rightChild;
         public Nodes leftChild;
         public  int value;

         public void InOrder()
          {
             if(leftChild != null)
                {
                  leftChild.InOrder();
                }

            Console.WriteLine(this.value);
            if(rightChild != null)
               {
                 rightChild.InOrder();
               }

           }

      }

    //Member of nodes class inside Binary tree class
    private Nodes root;

    //Default Constructor
    Binary_Tree() { }

    static void Main(string [] args)
    {

        Binary_Tree b = new Binary_Tree();
        b.Insertion(18);

        b.Insertion(10);
        b.Insertion(11);
        b.Insertion(5);
        b.Insertion(6);
        b.Insertion(3);
        b.root.InOrder();
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
}
```

My concern is with `leftChild.InOrder();` every time this function calls itself it moves from one `leftChild` to next `leftChild`. How is it possible because I think it should only move when there is an statement like `leftChild = leftChild.leftChild` or maybe `leftChild = leftChild.next`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @varocarbas: there is no extension method there. An extension method would be static.

Comment: This code is confusing. You should, at least, include the declaration of all the variables involved in order to allow us to understand it perfectly.

Comment: @WiktorZychla yes, I see that InOrder is not defined as an extension method but then how can it be associated with leftChild? Because both leftChild and rightChild are the containing class?! This is too weird and, in any case, there is not enough information.

Comment: @varocarbas: it is defined in a class, probably called Tree which has two properties of Tree type, leftChild and rightChild.

Comment: @WiktorZychla OK. Not completely sure that this is the only alternative, but pretty weird question with the information provided and, potential (because the OP hasn't still said a word) implementation.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I am still having some problems to see the exact point of this implementation. So, both properties are public and are instantiated before instantiating the given Tree variable (for example: test); but when you go through leftChild.InOrder(); (for instance), InOrder is called, which is the method of the current instance (test, not leftChild)... Unnecessarily complex/recurrent but, at a first sight, not even working!

Comment: @varocarbas: I can only recommend debugging this carefully.

Comment: @WiktorZychla no time now :) it was just out of curiousity. I find pretty curious when people over-complicate simple things. I will do the debugging tomorrow morning.

Comment: Sorry for the delay i was away from PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're learning Object Orientation, let's see if this helps (I know this is not strictly true as said, just mean to help a bit here).

In structured, you would do:

```
void InOrder(Tree node){ ... }
```

and then call like `InOrder(leftChild)`. This can be understood as: function `InOrder`, please, run yourself with `leftChild` as your `node` argument.

With objects, you have:

```
class Tree{
    void InOrder(){ ... }
}
```

and then call like `leftChild.InOrder()`. This can be understood as: object `leftChild`, please, run your method `InOrder`.

So you don't need to do something like `leftChild=leftChild.leftChild` because you tell your objects to run their respective method, and not the method to run with different arguments. That is, the method is run several times, each time with a different node.

Note that in OO every method is enclosed within a class, which explicitly means that every (non-static) method receives an argument of that type, which is `this` (the object we asked to run the method).

Answer (score 2):

This is because `leftChild` becomes `this` in the called method, which in turn has its own `leftChild` and `rightChild`.

What you miss probably here is that when you call an instance method on a reference, the reference becomes `this` in the called method.

Comment: Apparently you were completely right on what the OP's code was (I don't like using this kind of recursion, at all). But the OP didn't selected this answer?! Anyway... +1 because you were the first right one :)

Comment: Thanks for verifying this.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the code to show 'this' explicitly.

public class Tree 
 {

```
public Tree leftChild { get; set; }
public Tree rightChild { get; set; }

public object value { get; set; }   

public void InOrder()
{
    if(this.leftChild != null)
    {
        this.leftChild.InOrder();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(this.value);
    if(this.rightChild != null)
    {
        this.rightChild.InOrder();
    }
}
```

When you enter InOrder(), the current object is 'this'. The recursive call is made on the object 'this.leftChild', which is not the same object as 'this' (in fact it is the child object). That's how the recursion happens.